# Standard Deviation of 2 Datasets (Each Having Standard Deviation)

Tags: mean, standard-deviation

So say I had 2 datasets (each dataset is a set of values and each have a stanrdard deviation).

I want to find the mean difference between the two datasets elementwise e.g. ((element1_set1 - element1_set2) + (element2_set1 - element2_set2)) / 2 for two datasets of length 2.

Does this mean that I have to add the standard deviations elementwise and then find the mean of these to get the overall stanrdard deviation?

Or do I just find the mean and std of the array, [element1_set1 - element1_set2, element2_set1 - element2_set2]?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get why you mix in the standard deviation there.

For getting the mean difference, you can just subtract the means.
That works because of the following (assuming x are the elements of the first dataset and y the elements of the second):
[image]

But that doesn't work with standard deviation because of the squares.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm getting really confused as if there are multiple standard deviation, we must indlude all. However, if the standard deviation result from the same type of error, do we not have to include them?

Comment: What I wanted to say regarding the standard deviation: create a third dataset that contains the differences. Take the standard deviation of the new dataset. I think that is the best and most straight forward way. Ignore the standard deviations you have calculated for dataset 1 and 2.

Comment: I see, thank you. So can you just use the std of the final dataset becuase there is only one source of error? If there were more than one, would you have to take into consideration the std's of each individual set?

Comment: No, not as far as I can see. The std deviation of the dataset of differences will incorporate all variation there is in the differences of the two datasets.